# Sharing Values With a Class And Returning A Value Via Property

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

I don’t think I’m going to be able to explain myself very well, so sorry if this doesn’t make sense.

The example below has two functions that does some calculations that work fine:

```
Sub Example()

    Dim mValue = Multiply(2, 2)
    Dim dValue = Divide(2, 2)

End Sub

Function Multiply(ByVal value1 As Double, ByVal value2 As Double) As Double
    Return value1 * value2
End Function

Function Divide(ByVal value1 As Double, ByVal value2 As Double) As Double
    Return value1 / value2
End Function
```

What I would like to do is something similar to the below though (this doesn’t work but hopefully this demonstrates what I’m trying to do). I want to share parameters with a class and then select a property that return a value, similar to `DataGridView1.Item(1, 1).Size` for example. Sort of like a property inside a property, but I searched that and that didn't return any good results.

```
Sub example2()

    Dim mValue = Values(2, 2).Multiply()
    Dim dValue = Values(2, 2).Divide()

End Sub

Public Class Values

    Public Shared _Value1, _Value2 As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Value2 As Double)

        _Value1 = Value1
        _Value2 = Value2

    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Multiply() As Double

        Get
            Return _Value1 * _Value2
        End Get

    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Divide() As Double

        Get
            Return _Value1 / _Value2
        End Get

    End Property

End Class
```

I assume what I am trying to do is possible, I just think I’m missing something small. Any help or direction would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide whether you're going to use `Shared` members or instance members. You have a constructor that is not `Shared` so that means that you need to create an instance, which you do with the `New` keyword. If you create an instance then you need instance members to access on that instance:

```vb
Public Class Values

    Private value1 As Integer
    Private value2 As Integer

    Public Sub New(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer)
        Me.value1 = value1
        Me.value2 = value2
    End Sub

    Public Function Multiply() As Integer
        Return value1 * value2
    End Function

    Public Function Divide() As Double
        Return value1 / value2
    End Function

End Class
```

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim values = New Values(2, 2)
    Dim product = values.Multiply()
    Dim quotient = values.Divide()
End Sub
```

The alternative is to use all `Shared` members and not create an instance at all. the data goes in via `Shared` properties and out via `Shared` methods:

```vb
Public Class Values

    Public Shared Property Value1 As Integer
    Public Shared Property Value2 As Integer

    Public Shared Function Multiply() As Integer
        Return Value1 * Value2
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Divide() As Double
        Return Value1 / Value2
    End Function

End Class
```

```vb
Sub Example()
    Values.Value1 = 2
    Values.Value2 = 2

    Dim product = Values.Multiply()
    Dim quotient = Values.Divide()
End Sub
```

In the first case, you would create a `Values` instance where you wanted to use it and any other code that created a different instance would have no effect on that. In the second case, because there is only one set of properties for the class, you might set them in one place and then set them to something else in a second place, then call a method in the first place and expect the result to make use of the first set of property values. With only one set of fields, the methods will always use the last of values assigned to them, no matter where in the code that happened.

It's also worth noting that, if you are thinking of defining a class with all `Shared` members, you probably ought to define a module instead. Modules are compiled as classes behind the scenes and they inherently prevent you creating an instance, so module members behave like `Shared` class members. The difference is that you don't have to qualify module members with the name of the module, where you do have to qualify `Shared` class members. Some people don't like that and incorrectly think that it breaks the rules of OOP. You still can qualify module members if you want to but classes force you to.

If you want a one-liner then you can do that with both instance members and `Shared` members, but they will look a bit different. If you're using instance members then you need an instance, so you must invoke a constructor. There's no requirement to keep that object around though. You can use it and throw it away if you want, e.g.

```vb
Dim product = New Values(2, 2).Multiply()
```

That's slightly wasteful if you're performing multiple operations on the same numbers though, because you'll be creating multiple identical instance, e.g.

```vb
Dim product = New Values(2, 2).Multiply()
Dim quotient = New Values(2, 2).Divide()
```

If you're using `Shared` members then you'd have to overload the methods to allow you to pass in values or not:

```vb
Public Class Values

    Public Shared Property Value1 As Integer
    Public Shared Property Value2 As Integer

    Public Overloads Shared Function Multiply() As Integer
        Return Value1 * Value2
    End Function

    Public Overloads Shared Function Multiply(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer) As Integer
        Values.Value1 = value1
        Values.Value2 = value2

        Return Multiply()
    End Function

    Public Overloads Shared Function Divide() As Double
        Return Value1 / Value2
    End Function

    Public Overloads Shared Function Divide(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer) As Double
        Values.Value1 = value1
        Values.Value2 = value2

        Return Divide()
    End Function

End Class
```

You can then pass in new values when you call a method or use the existing values, e.g.

```vb
Dim product = Values.Multiply(2, 2)
Dim quotient = Values.Divide()
```

Comment: Everything you have explained make sense, I was hoping this could have be achieved with one line like the Values(2, 2).Multiply(), but both example above will require multiple lines. Thats all good though, this answers my question and the simplicity I was sort of chasing doesn't look like exist in the way I would like. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarron, it can be done in one line if you're using instance members, but you need to create an instance: `Dim product = New Values(2, 2).Multiply()`. If you're using `Shared` members then you could overload the methods to set the properties and calculate or just calculate. I'll update the answer with further explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct if anything I missed , here I create class library

```
Namespace calulation

    Public Class Operations

        Private i_v1 As Integer
        Private i_v2 As Integer

        Private obj_mul As Multiply
        Private d_value As Double
        Public ReadOnly Property Multiply As Double
            Get
                obj_mul = New Multiply(i_v1, i_v2)
                d_value = obj_mul.GetValues
                Return d_value
            End Get
        End Property

        Private obj_divide As Divide
        Public ReadOnly Property Divide As Double
            Get
                obj_divide = New Divide(i_v1, i_v2)
                d_value = obj_divide.GetValues
                Return d_value
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub New(ByVal v1 As Integer, ByVal v2 As Integer)


            i_v1 = v1
            i_v2 = v2



        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class Multiply


        Private Shared s_value1 As Integer
        Private Shared s_value2 As Integer
        Public Sub New(ByVal v1 As Integer, ByVal v2 As Integer)

            s_value1 = v1
            s_value2 = v2
        End Sub
        Public Function GetValues() As Double
            Return s_value1 * s_value2
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class Divide
        Private Shared s_value1 As Integer
        Private Shared s_value2 As Integer

        Public Sub New(ByVal v1 As Integer, ByVal v2 As Integer)

            s_value1 = v1
            s_value2 = v2
        End Sub
        Public Function GetValues() As Double
            Try
                Return s_value1 / s_value2
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try

        End Function
    End Class

End Namespace
```

Now put reference of that library to your windows form project

```
Imports calculation.calulation


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Try
            Dim obj As Double = New Operations(2, 3).Multiply

            Dim obj2 As Double = New Operations(2, 3).Divide



            MsgBox(obj.ToString)
            MsgBox(obj2.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try




    End Sub
```